# Errors when importing files into spyder (Correct directory)

Tags: python, csv, pandas, anaconda, spyder

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
all_ages = pd.read_csv("all-ages.csv")
all_ages.head(5)
```

And I have already put the csv file in the working directory, but I still encounter

> OSError: File b'all-ages.csv' does not exist

But if I type each line in the Console instead of Script, it works sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better provide the **absolute file path**. Python uses the current working directory which depends on where you invoke/run your python script.

Even you put your python script and csv file "all-ages.csv" under the same directory, the current working directory might be different.

For example:

```
/folder1/folder2/myscript.py
/folder1/folder2/all-ages.csv
```

if you run `python myscript.py` under directory folder2, it can find all-ages.csv, but if you invoke `python folder2/myscript.py` under folder1, the current working directory is folder1, and it cannot find `all-ages.csv`